# What is a cold black hole in astrophysics?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature, astrophysics, terminology

I found the word 'Cold Black hole' in some academic papers. I think it is concerned with thermodynamics of black hole but I don't know exactly what is cold black hole. Please help me to understand well.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Instead of "some academic papers", it often helps if you give at least one concrete reference to a source.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, here I have sent the link of the paper. https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0008025

Comment: @MinThawTar: When someone asks for a clarification or more information, it's best to include it in the question by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

“Cold black hole” is *not* a standard terminology, so looking at the paper OP has cited, we see that this is the name for a class of black-hole type solutions in [scalar-tensor theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar%E2%80%93tensor_theory) (STT) with an infinite horizon area and zero Hawking temperature, existing for negative values of the coupling constant $ω$ (Brans–Dicke parameter).

To learn more about the properties of these solutions one could turn to the papers:

- Bronnikov, K. A., et al. *Structure and stability of cold scalar-tensor black holes.* Physics Letters A 243.3 (1998): 121–127, [arXiv:gr-qc/9801050](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9801050).
- Bronnikov, K. A., et al. *Cold scalar-tensor black holes: causal structure, geodesics, stability*. Grav. Cosmol. 4 (1998) 128–138, [arXiv:gr-qc/9804064](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9804064).